# Catalog rules daily update doesn't work

Tags: rules, catalog, cron

I face with problem that Magento's Catalog rules daily update doesn't work. This means that there are no products price changes when catalog rule's expire date comes, so I have to press rule apply button in Admin.
Cron is configured and working. It seems that catalogrule/observer::dailyCatalogUpdate method should check and apply rules automatically every day, but it doesn't (also I've tried to launch it manually).
Here is Magento core code:

```
<!--file: app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/etc/config.xml-->
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <catalogrule_apply_all>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>catalogrule/observer::dailyCatalogUpdate</model>
            </run>
        </catalogrule_apply_all>
    </jobs>
    ...
</crontab>
```

Observer:

```
/*file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Observer.php*/
public function dailyCatalogUpdate($observer)
{
    Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalogrule/rule')->applyAllRulesForDateRange();

    return $this;
}
```

I had a success modifying observer method as below:

```
/*file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Observer.php*/
public function dailyCatalogUpdate($observer)
{
    Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->getResourceCollection()
                  ->walk(array(
                         Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalogrule/rule'),
                         'updateRuleProductData'
                  ));
    Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalogrule/rule')->applyAllRulesForDateRange();

    return $this;
}
```

This way rules are checked and applied every day and products prices are being changed if rule expire.
I don't believe that it is a bug of Magento. Please, advise  what is the problem that rules are not being checked and applied automatically?

Comment: Are there any errors being logged to your PHP error log or the messages column on the cron_schedule table? I'm assuming the cron is in fact being called since you indicated you'd had some success by modifying the observer method.

Comment: Also you can place some log calls in original observer and see if it gets called. Just to be safe on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recently I had the same problem when I was testing a new price rule for our project. And the reason of my headache was that I did not notice that every time when you create a new rule or edit some of the existing rules - you should press "**Apply Rules**" button to make Magento know about your rule changes.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right: saving rule is not enough for changes. It would be great to have extra column in rules grid saying if rule was applied or not.

Comment: The dailyCatalogUpdate is suppose to apply rules nightly if you don't press that button. Otherwise what is the purpose of that cron?

Answer (score 7):

Making sure to hit "Apply Rules" is not always enough. I recently discovered that if cron is not set up properly, at some point in the future, the rules will not be applied.

I was unable to really nail down when the rules stopped working. In my case I had a handful of rules that are applied based on customer group (wholesale).

> 1. Check the `cron_schedule` table. Make sure you have some entries here corresponding to `catalogrule_apply_all` (I think that's the
>      process name).
> 2. Set the cronjob in the CatalogRule module's `config.xml` file to run every minute or so (for testing) with */1.
> 3. Look back at the `cron_schedule` table, and keep reloading it every couple of minutes. You should see new processes get added/executed
>      automatically **without** ever having to manually hit your store's
>      `cron.php` file.
> 4. If you aren't seeing any of the processes update manually, SSH into the site as the user who owns the site's files. From a command line:
>      `crontab -e` (you may be in Vim and not know what to do, I suggest
>      google on using basic Vim commands).
> 5. Set the crontab to run: `*/1 * * * *  /path/to/your/cron.sh`
> 6. Now check the `cron_schedule` table again to make sure that cron processes are executing automatically.
> 7. Hopefully, all is good at this point. Go ahead and go back and set your cron processes to run at the desired intervals.

Answer (score 3):

**Check if the job gets scheduled**

You can do this by either checking the database or install this extension: [Aoe_Scheduler](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-cron-scheduler.html)

**Test if the job works**

Create a php script `run_my_rules.php` and put in there only the content for the function: `dailyCatalogUpdate` then run that from the console. See what is happening.